# LongListSelector and DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector, datatemplateselector

I'm using the LongListSelector to realize List or Grid display for my items. For this, I created a DataTemplateSelector and I change the LayoutMode property at runtime. This is working but there seems to be an issue with the DataTemplateSelector. If I initially launch the page, the DataTemplateSelector is called three times for my three items. When I navigate to another page (settings page to change the LayoutMode) and then back, the DataTemplateSelector is just called two items but there are still three items.

DataTemplateSelector:

```
public abstract class DataTemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    public virtual DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, this);
    }
}
```

ItemViewModeTemplateSelector:

```
public class ItemViewModeTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ListViewModeTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate GridViewModeTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ViewMode viewMode = ViewMode.Grid;

        // Get ViewMode from IsolatedStorageSettings...

        switch (viewMode)
        {
            case ViewMode.Grid:
                return GridViewModeTemplate;

            case ViewMode.List:
                return ListViewModeTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ItemLongListSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="222,222">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <common:ItemViewModeTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <common:ItemViewModeTemplateSelector.GridViewModeTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="12,12,0,0" Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}">
                            <!-- Content -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </common:ItemViewModeTemplateSelector.GridViewModeTemplate>

                <common:ItemViewModeTemplateSelector.ListViewModeTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <!-- Content -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </common:ItemViewModeTemplateSelector.ListViewModeTemplate>
            </common:ItemViewModeTemplateSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

This is the display when I initially launch the page:
[image]

Then I navigate to another page and then back:
[image]

EDIT: I prepared a sample project for this issue. It should run without problems.

Project: http://sdrv.ms/1cAbVxE

Comment: I've added a sample project!

Comment: did you find the problem?

Comment: No, the problem is still there!

Comment: indeed that was very curious question, i know it sounds kind of lame but, if you use ListBox and bind ItemTemplate?

Comment: I'm already using ListBox but I wanto to switch to the LongListSelector because it does not work really good with ContextMenu. You can see my issue with ListBox here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609850/windows-phone-listbox-with-tiles-and-contextmenu-isenabled-binding-does-not-w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something similar with my app, but allowed the user to choose the LayoutMode of LLS using an Appbar button. I basically change the LongListSelector.LayoutMode and then it's ItemTemplate in code and the LLS automatically refreshes itself. I'm not sure if this will help, but here's my code.

```
private void layoutModeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationBarIconButton layoutModeButton = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];

        if (MainLongListSelector.LayoutMode == LongListSelectorLayoutMode.Grid)
        {
            MainLongListSelector.LayoutMode = LongListSelectorLayoutMode.List;
            MainLongListSelector.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["ListListLayout"] as DataTemplate;
            layoutModeButton.IconUri = _gridButtonUri;
            layoutModeButton.Text = "grid";
        }
        else
        {
            MainLongListSelector.LayoutMode = LongListSelectorLayoutMode.Grid;
            MainLongListSelector.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["GridListLayout"] as DataTemplate;
            layoutModeButton.IconUri = _listButtonUri;
            layoutModeButton.Text = "list";
        }
    }
```

You might have figured out the answer already, but just to add to the conversation: this gives me really good performance for a fairly large amount of data. Maybe you can do something similar when navigating back to the page after changing the layout in settings?

Comment: This works too! It seems to be the more performance-friendly way I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't got the solution but maybe a clue for someone who will solve the problem.
I think the problem is with LongListSelector.UpdateLayout() method - when it's fired for the first time there are no items to which LLS was bound - OnChangeMethod is called that many times as the Itemsource.Count. But when we leave the page and go back - LLS is Updated and method is called ommiting the middle element.
It means it works for even number of items - OnChangeMethod is called correct number of times, But for odd number of items - it's called numer of items - 1.
The second thing is why it's called at all - when there are no changes.

I also add a [code](http://sdrv.ms/17qDLdk) to work on which (very simple).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one walk around. (Maybe the problem will be corrected with WP 8.1 Update, along with [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356668/long-list-selector-observable-collection-and-visual-tree-problems) I've spotted working with LLS. I know - this idea is ugly, hard and so on, but maybe it will be enough for your purpose:

Becouse the problem concerns 'reloading' LLS, I've forced it to initialize it every time I navigate to the page (in fact I need to initialize the whole Page - it won't work only with LLS). I've moved InitializeComponent() and buttons events and so on to OnNavigatedTo():

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

     this._contentLoaded = false;
     InitializeComponent();

     first.Click += first_Click;
     second.Click += second_Click;
     ItemLongListSelector.ItemsSource = Items;
  }
```

At least OnContentChanged() is fired that many Times its needed. Code you can find [here](http://sdrv.ms/HNOGlZ).

Comment: This works but I'm not sure how it will impact on my performance with much items. I will test it and if it is too bad I will remove the option of changing the layout mode. Thank you, this helps me a lot! :)